# Resulting momenta of two balls after inelastic collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Suppose two aligned equal balls, or spheres (same dimension, mass, energy, linear momentum, etc.) having an inelastic collision along the x-axis, with no background friction. Each sphere can have different angular momenta, analytically represented as respectively x-axis, y-axis and z-axis rotations.
What are the resulting angular momenta of each ball after the collisions of each possible combination of momenta?
Example:
Ball 1, with nu angular momentum + Ball 2, with x-axis angular momentum.
Ball 1, with nu angular momentum + Ball 2, with y-axis (left or right) angular momentum.
Ball 1, with nu angular momentum + Ball 2, with z-axis (up or down) angular momentum.
Then, Ball 1, with x-axis and z-axis angular momenta + Ball 2, with (similar) x-axis and (opposite) z-axis momenta.
And so on.
Is it possible to model this / to draw a table of results?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your interest! Ok then: Keeping in mind all the conditions above, I would like to know what are the angular momenta, after an inelastic collision, of two balls, one having, say, no angular momentum, and the second an angular momentum around the x axis (like a helicity-spin).

Comment: I am not interested in calculating the precise values, only in the resulting rotations. For example, would the first ball remain with no angular momentum, or would it acquire also an angular momentum from the second ball? Would the second ball conserve its rotation, or it will lose it?